# Index pandas data frame by index

Tags: python, pandas

sample dataframe:

```
data = [["2011-01-01",23],["2011-01-02",33],["2011-01-03",43],["2011-01-04",53]]
df= pd.DataFrame(data,columns = ["A","B"])
df["A"] = pd.to_datetime(df["A"])
df.index = df["A"]
del df["A"]
```

OP:

```
            B
A   
2011-01-01  23
2011-01-02  33
2011-01-03  43
2011-01-04  53
```

I am trying to split this data frame in two parts using the following code:

```
part1 = df.loc[:"2011-01-02"]
```

op:

```
            B
A   
2011-01-01  23
2011-01-02  33
```

part2:

```
part2 = df.loc["2011-01-02":]
```

op:

```
            B
A   
2011-01-02  33
2011-01-03  43
2011-01-04  53
```

But the row with index "2011-01-02" is in both the parts(part1 and part2). Any suggestions for pandas 1-liners to get that row in just 1 part and not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `get_loc` with `iloc`

```
df.iloc[:df.index.get_loc('2011-01-02')]
                    A   B
A                        
2011-01-01 2011-01-01  23

df.iloc[df.index.get_loc('2011-01-02'):]
                    A   B
A                        
2011-01-02 2011-01-02  33
2011-01-03 2011-01-03  43
2011-01-04 2011-01-04  53
```

Answer (score 2):

The behavior is expected (I don't know it until today either)

> This type of slicing will work on a DataFrame with a DatetimeIndex as
>   well. Since the partial string selection is a form of label slicing,
>   the endpoints will be included. This would include matching times on
>   an included date:
>   from http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/timeseries.html#indexing.

And about the label slicing behavior

> Note that contrary to usual python slices, both the start and the stop are included
>   https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas.DataFrame.loc

```
In [16]: df[df.index < '2011-01-02']
Out[16]:
             B
A
2011-01-01  23

In [17]: df[df.index >= '2011-01-02']
Out[17]:
             B
A
2011-01-02  33
2011-01-03  43
2011-01-04  53

In [18]: df[df.index > '2011-01-02']
Out[18]:
             B
A
2011-01-03  43
2011-01-04  53
```

Answer (score 2):

```
slice = df.index > "2011-01-02"
df[slice]
df[~slice]
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `part2 = df.loc["2011-01-02":]` use

```py
part2 = df.loc["2011-01-02":].iloc[1:]

             B
A             
2011-01-03  43
2011-01-04  53
```